# Finding the SUM of values of a column of all records in sql 2005

Tags: t-sql, subquery

I want to find the *SUM* of values in a column **weight**. I want this sum for all records that are identified with a common value in one of the columns **name**. Further, I want to consider only those records that have a certain value in the column **type**.    
                                                                                name               weight      type
   1     `$`          12.00        A
   2     `$`          7.00         B
   2     `$`         7.00         A
   1     `$`          1.00         C
   2     `$`          7.00         B
   1     `$`          1.00         C
   2     `$`          7.00         B
   1     `$`          7.00         B
   2     `$`         7.00         C
   2     `$`          7.00         B

I want the total weight for name 2, for the types A and B. Can a subquery be written for this or only looping can be done. Tnx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this really depends on ones interpretation of the OPs question, which is a little vague to me.  But give this a try:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Weight)
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Name=2 AND Type IN ('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Type,
    SUM(Weight)
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    Name,
    Type
HAVING
    Name = @name
AND
    Type = @type
```

Or to be specific for your request

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Type,
    SUM(Weight)
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    Name,
    Type
HAVING
    Name = '2'
AND
    Type IN('A', 'B')
```

However, if it is purely a single value you are after for your filter then you can just SUM with a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    SUM(Weight)
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    Name = '2'
AND
    Type IN('A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show you the sum of weights for each name, where the type is A or B:

```
select name, sum(weight) as WeightSum
from MyTable t
where type in ('A', 'B')
group by name
```